# GridView width based on ItemsSource

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime

I am currently using a `GridView` to display a list of images that the user can swipe through. When they get close to the end of the list, new images load through the use of a `ObservableCollection` that implements `ISupportIncrementalLoading`.

How do I change the cell size to match the size of the image? The images are sometimes in Portrait, and sometimes in Landscape, and sometimes in an non-uniform aspect ratio; however, the `GridView` insists on all the cells being the same width.

e.g. if I go with the following:

```
<GridView
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    TabIndex="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Padding="116,136,116,46"
    SelectionMode="None"
    DataFetchSize="10"
    IncrementalLoadingThreshold="5"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
    IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge"
    IsSwipeEnabled="false">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="30" Margin="15,0,5,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I end up with all the times being the same width as the first image. If I try to set the image width (I have a databound property that returns the image width), some of the images end up being less wide, but the cell they are in is still the same width as everything else.

```
<Image Width="{Binding ImageWidth}" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
```

Setting the width on any item in the hierarchy doesn't seem to help - even taking this to the extreme doesn't help at all - e.g.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="{Binding ImageWidth}">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="{Binding ImageWidth}">
            <Image Width="{Binding ImageWidth}" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
         </Border>
         <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="30" Margin="15,0,5,0"/>
         </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ItemsPanelTemplate-s that supports incremental loading: VirtualizingStackPanel and WrapGrid.
WrapGrid does not allow different items' size.
VirtualizingStackPanel allows variable size of items but displays items in one row/column.
So if you want a different layout you need a custom implementation of VirtualizingPanel.

But I do not understand what do you want exactly. If you want a grid then all items in a row or column will have the same height or width. Do you want a virtualizing VariableSizedWrapGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [VariableSizedWrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid)

try to add this xaml to your GridView declaration:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```